# WCF переделать helpPage

Tags: c#, wcf

Всем привет! Суть вопроса: имеется проект WebApi к которому позднее была добавлена WCF. У webApi есть встроеный механизм HelpPage, достаточно удобный, но возникла необходимость сделать это и для методов WCF. Стандартный HelpPage не очень порадовал, нету описания входных и выходных параметров, пришлось писать свой.

Вопрос: Как создать свой адекватный HelpPage для WCF(может кто то делал или видел статью) или модернизировать стандартный?

Comment: Не уверен, что это полностью решит ваши проблемы, но указанная статья возможно будет отправной точкой. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Help-Page-6f5a90f0

Comment: @sp7 в поле ответ и можно будет подумать об [ассоциации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051393/can-a-wcf-service-display-a-help-page-or-other-content). Никто не хочет вкратце перевести основные моменты из статьи? Вопрос реально неплохой, было бы полезно.